# phpunit/seleniumRC/selenium2testcase elements off page unclickable in firefox

Tags: firefox, phpunit, selenium-rc

So my company is asking me to expand my automated tests for more support of other browsers, namely firefox and safari.

My original suite was designed in Chrome and for the most part, it works pretty flawlessly, and exposes bugs immediately -- a very helpful tool indeed.

I have about 80 testcases that require page navigation and clicks on dynamic urls. This works fine for me up until testcase 7 (and above) which the element I need to click is off the page.  How do I know this is the root problem?  Because if I put a sleep before the click command and manually scroll the page during firefox execution, the click actually occurs, and I get navigated to the correct page...

Does anyone have a solution for this?  I could have swore SeleniumTestCase2 was suppose to remove this issue?  I'll post my code below but honestly it works in chrome driver, but not in firefox.

Firefox v43.0 and Selenium jar 4.48.2

```php
protected function selectModule($module = NULL)
{
    $this->module = $module;
    $this->module = strtolower($this->module);
    $this->byID($this->module)->click();
    $this->assertEquals($this->url(SOMECONSTANTEXPECTEDURL), $this->byXpath('/html/head/base')->text());
    fwrite(STDERR, print_r(__METHOD__."()->$this->module method completed.".PHP_EOL, TRUE));
    return $this;
}
```

Full Stack trace (as requested):

```
19:44:56.100 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: ggk5y3m1])
19:44:56.106 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: ggk5y3m1]
19:44:56.124 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: ggk5y3m1])
19:44:56.131 INFO - Done: [find element: By.id: ggk5y3m1]
19:44:56.142 INFO - Executing: [click: 6 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (a9
587de1-e110-454c-b6cb-581612242081)] -> id: ggk5y3m1]])
19:44:56.306 INFO - Done: [click: 6 [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (a9587de
1-e110-454c-b6cb-581612242081)] -> id: ggk5y3m1]]
19:44:56.308 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: ff_frame442])
19:44:57.334 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":
"id","selector":"ff_frame442"}
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/
no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'testing', ip: '10.1.20.115', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true
, databaseEnabled=true, version=43.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acce
ptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserNam
e=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=tru
e}]
Session ID: a9587de1-e110-454c-b6cb-581612242081
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=ff_frame442}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.
java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHa
ndler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:647)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDrive
r.java:353)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebD
river.java:403)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDrive
r.java:345)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(Even
tFiringWebDriver.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.findElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(E
ventFiringWebDriver.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElemen
t.java:48)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElemen
t.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession
.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
 {"method":"id","selector":"ff_frame442"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/
no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'testing', ip: '10.1.20.115', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:/
//C:/Users/SIMON~1.KYG/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2462846570487533916webdriver-
profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)
        at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/User
s/SIMON~1.KYG/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2462846570487533916webdriver-profile/e
xtensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10668)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file://
/C:/Users/SIMON~1.KYG/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2462846570487533916webdriver-p
rofile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C
:/Users/SIMON~1.KYG/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2462846570487533916webdriver-pro
file/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12539)
        at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users
/SIMON~1.KYG/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2462846570487533916webdriver-profile/ex
tensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12481)
19:44:57.338 WARN - Exception: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selecto
r":"ff_frame442"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/
no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'testing', ip: '10.1.20.115', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: can you post stacktrace message with exception?

Comment: included full stack trace for you.

Comment: 19:44:56.308 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.id: ff_frame442])
19:44:57.334 WARN - Exception thrown

occurs over and over. because ff_frame442 is what I'm expecting next, but it never comes because the click never occurred...

Comment: Did you try to scroll to element before clicking? (via selenium)

Comment: I tried $this->moveto($this->byID($this->module)); and I got unexpected results.... it took me to the completely wrong expected page after simulating $this->click();

I wonder if it's due to the floating footer?

Comment: I was only ever taken to the correct destination page in firefox, if i manually put a sleep in before the click() call, and then scrolled the window down (manually) until the link was exposed.

Comment: Can you also add `wait` before click?

Comment: I tried both a sleep(5); and

        $this->waitUntil(function () 
        {
            if ($this->byId($this->module))
            {
                return true;
            }
            sleep(1);
            return null;
        }, 20000);

Comment: neither of the above gave any different results.  the stack trace is actually showing that a click occurred.  how can that be possible if the page isn't redirecting me?  it doesn't make sense.

Comment: if you can share the link to page and id of the element I can try to figure out in python bindings =P

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Drets

Code that solved it (a wait for both moving to the damned element and then a wait before clicking it, SMH....)

```
    self::waitforID($this->module);
    $this->moveto($this->byID($this->module));
    self::waitforID($this->module);
    $this->byID($this->module)->click();

//
...
//
    protected function waitforID($ID)
    {
        $this->waitUntil(function () use ($ID) 
        {
            if ($this->byId($ID))
            {
                return true;
            }
            sleep(1);
            return null;
        }, 120000);
    }
```